# How to add a record to the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add a record to the user model to make it the admin user.

```
 @u = User.new(email: 'admin@gmail.com')
 @u.save
```

when i `rake db:migrate` i get this error

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'users'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:517:in `table_structure'
```

Yeah i used devise to create a registration login

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profiles
  # One user has one profile only
  @u= User.new 
  @u.admin@gmail.com


end
```

**add_admin_to_users.rb**

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

**update_users.rb**

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    @u = User.find_by( email: 'admin@gmail.com')
    @u.update_attribute :admin , true
  #@u.update_attributes(:admin ,true) 
  end
end
```

**error**

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass/home/ubuntu/workspace/hrApp/db/migrate/20150404180803_update_users.rb:6:in `change'
```

Comment: Did you create the table users with some migration?

Comment: Why are you specifying this is html/javascript in your question?

Comment: Im not this is model and migration based.

Comment: @RonanBrady can you show the entire code for the user model? It seems you have some code that's being executed in your model when the file is required as seen by `/home/ubuntu/workspace/hrApp/app/models/user.rb:12:in '<class:User>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/hrApp/app/models/user.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
 @u = User.new(email: 'admin@gmail.com')
 @u.save
```

to `app/db/seeds.rb`. Then `rake db:migrate` to create table (if it does not yet exist) and `rake db:seed` to create any data you like (an admin user in this case) in this table

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Its moved the next migration update users.rb. I'll include the code. But the next error is the reason i want a record of 'admin@gmail.com'

Comment: @RonanBrady, that's because user with this email is not found. You should create it first. And I would move all the code that is not associated with database structure out of migration. Migrations are for creating/modifying table structure. If you want to add or modify data inside of tables, there is `seeds.rb` for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you seem to have some code that's being executed when rails loads the environment during your `rake db:migrate` command.

This means you probably have some code that looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ... some other code
  @u = User.new(email: 'admin@gmail.com')
  @u.save
end
```

That code is executed when rake loads the rails environment which is probably not what you want or should be doing in any case.

Move the code to create the new admin to your `db/seed.rb` file. Then you can execute the migrations and then seed your database by running `rake db:seed`

Also, don't use migrations to modify data in your database for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Cheers Leo. Yes that's what I have in the user model. I ll try do what Ivan has explained below